# Sound coming out of both headphones and speakers

Tags: 18.04

I use ubuntu and recently the sound comes out of both speakers and headphones.
I know that this question has been asked before but none of them have solved my problem.
Also when I mute speakers from pavucontrol and alsamixer and then select headphones as output device from settings it automatically increases speaker's volume.
[Sound output settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCqUE.png)

In the screenshot above I notice that by headphones are built in audio. Is it normal.
I am new to ubuntu so please explain me like I am a 5 year old

Output of:/tmp/pulseverbose.log
https://pastebin.com/202edPHt

Output of command sudo gedit /etc/pulse/client.conf

```
    ; default-sink =
; default-source =
; default-server =
; default-dbus-server =

; autospawn = yes
; daemon-binary = /usr/bin/pulseaudio
; extra-arguments = --log-target=syslog

; cookie-file =

; enable-shm = yes
; shm-size-bytes = 0 # setting this 0 will use the system-default, usually 64 MiB

; auto-connect-localhost = no
; auto-connect-display = no
extra-arguments = -vvvv --log-target=newfile:/tmp/pulseverbose.log --log-time=1
```

Comment: it could be you have `paprefs` installed and have simultaneous output enabled, open paprefs, does it look like this : https://www.maketecheasier.com/assets/uploads/2018/01/sa-paprefs.jpg? if paprefs is not installed it would be something else. Also add a screenshot to your post showing what audio settings you have for the "ouput" tab.

Comment: I dont have paprefs. What do you mean by audio settings of output tab.

Comment: click this : https://imgur.com/mbybJg8 then go to (or type) "sound".

Comment: I have already posted a screenshot about that. Oh sorry didnt add description

Comment: Okay, I'm a bit out of my depth here so I'll pass the relay to someone else but could you add the output of `cat /proc/asound/cards` ,  `aplay -l`, `pactl list` and also could you do `sudo echo "extra-arguments = -vvvv --log-target=newfile:/tmp/pulseverbose.log --log-time=1" >> /etc/pulse/client.conf` and reboot, please?

Comment: I can add the screenshots but the third command has at least 15 screenshots. Also the third command you gave there is an error in terminal.                                           sudo echo "extra-arguments = -vvvv --log-target=newfile:/tmp/pulseverbose.log --log-time=1" >> /etc/pulse/client.conf

Comment: actually you're supposed to 1. highlight the whole result (if it's really long click at the begining, use the scroll bar to get to the end, then "shift-click" onto the end of the last line, this will highlight everything between the two clicks) and then 2. copy it with "ctrl-shift-c" and then 3. edit your original post and paste it into it with "ctrl-v", then 4. select the text again and click the `{}` symbol to format it as code. then 5. save the edits to your post.

Comment: also sorry, I meant `echo "extra-arguments = -vvvv --log-target=newfile:/tmp/pulseverbose.log --log-time=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/pulse/client.conf` you can check the file with  `sudo gedit /etc/pulse/client.conf` to make sure I only made you add that line at the end once.

Comment: I did it. Check the new Image.Thank you for hanging out so long

Comment: ok good. this means you're now logging info. (you need to reboot for this to take effect) as a test, could you run `sudo apt install paprefs -y && paprefs` ? and go to the simultaneous tab : https://www.maketecheasier.com/assets/uploads/2018/01/sa-paprefs.jpg if the box is ticked this is interesting, if it is unticked it is interesting as well, in both cases we will try something : tick or untick the box and then reboot. if you were in the "ticked" case before do nothing else, if you were in the "unticked" case open up paprefs again and now untick it like it was right at the start and reboot.

Comment: This didn't work

Comment: could you include the contents of  : `/tmp/pulseverbose.log` in your post? this time just copy and paste the text. select it again before clicking "save" on your post edit and click this icon `{}` to format it as code, then save edit.

Comment: I cant because body is limited to 30000 characters

Comment: ok then you can use https://pastebin.com/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/202edPHt                                                                                                I will try redownloading driver

Comment: add it to you main post please. I'm not the only one on this website susceptible/trying to help you out, people aren't going to go scrolling through miles of comments, if you want help, make it easier for help to get to you. also include those original screenshots as copy pasted code instead. those do fit in the 30000 characters.